# Can you use MODI OCR to process checkboxes (non alpha non numeric characters/items)?

Tags: vb.net, ocr, modi

I have a vb.net application successfully processing the text in TIF files, but it is ignoring the checkboxes. Is there anyway to use MODI to process anything within the file that is not text? Such as a mark that a person has made with a pen inside a checkbox? I think I would need to be able to evaluate where the pixels are. This is for a zero budget personal project. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MODI is capable of OCR and what you describe is called ICR (intelligent checkmark recognition). As far as i know, there are no free/open source tools/SDKs that provide such data capture functionality, there are some low-budget solutions ([this one](http://ocrsdk.com/) for example, free 90 days trial and processing one checkmark pricing starts from $0.008).